# Creating a vector of sslstreams

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

For latency sake I'm trying to generate a few sockets that have already performed connect and handshake to save a few milliseconds. When I try to use "push_back" the new ssl stream onto the vector I get "Description Location    Resource    Path    Type
‘boost::asio::basic_io_object::basic_io_object(const boost::asio::basic_io_object&) [with IoObjectService = boost::asio::deadline_timer_service >]’ is private   line 163, external location: /boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp Test3       C/C++ Problem"

```
void QueueSocket() {    

    using namespace boost::network;

    boost::system::error_code ec;

    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
    typedef ssl::stream<tcp::socket> ssl_socket;


std::vector<boost::asio::io_service> vecStreams;
vecStreams.emplace_back();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` owns its elements, which means it tries to either move or copy new values. `sockconn` is not a temporary, so it won't be moved, and it can't be copied.

In this case, I think you're fine with moving it - you don't use `sockconn` after the push_back anyway. So : `vecStreams.push_back(std::move(sockconn));`.

Comment: I had to remove std:: as it said move is not a member of std. After that I get the following errors, 
‘boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>::basic_io_object(const boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>&) [with IoObjectService = boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >]’ is private line 163, external location: /boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp Test3  C/C++ Problem

Comment: @RGibson1972: `move` definitely is a member of `std`. And I definitely mean `std::move`, not some random other function that also happens to be named `move`. There are 2 possibilities: either you didn't include the necessary header (`<utility>`)  or your compiler is outdated.

Comment: These are my compilers,  gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
Please advise. Thahnks

Comment: It looks like my compiler is old, can I just use the boost::move?

Comment: @RGibson1972: Not that simple, boost::move is tied to boost containers.

Comment: Okay will wrestle with installing a new compiler and will let you know the results. Thanks

Comment: I ended up getting the new gcc installed fine, I now get this error "/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/noncopyable.hpp:32:3: error: ‘boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::asio::detail::noncopyable&)’ is private"

Comment: @RGibson1972: indeed, streams are non-copyable, which is why you'd need to move them. An alternative might be to construct them in place, using `emplace_back`

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, I tried ecStreams.emplace_back(sockconn); and I get the same errors.

Comment: @RGibson1972: When you use `emplace_back`, you should provide the constructor arguments (i.e. `emplace_back(io_service, ctxPull)`)  and then continue to prepare the new `.back()` element.

Comment: I think I'm doing it as you say but still getting non-copyable error. using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
 namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
 typedef ssl::stream<tcp::socket> ssl_socket;
 std::vector<boost::asio::io_service> vecSockets;
 strAPIServer = "google.com";
 strBoundIP = "192.168.196.142";

 boost::asio::io_service io_service;
 vecSockets.emplace_back(io_service);
 ssl_socket sockconn(io_service, ctxPull);

Comment: @RGibson1972: You're creating the `io_service` object outside the vector, and then try to copy it in. That won't work. Also, why did the type of vector change?

Comment: I have changed the vector type a few times trying different things. I'm confused as to how to create io_service within vector. Will it maintained it's state that way? For instance if I perform the ssl handshake and connect?

Comment: @RGibson1972: C++ objects almost without exception don't care where they're stored. As I said, you create an `io_service` in a vector of `io_service`s by calling `emplace_back` and passing the necessary parameters for the `io_service` ctor.

Comment: I have updated the above code, I am receiving "boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::asio::detail::noncopyable" I believe io_service is being created within the vector this way as it doesn't need any paramters however still receiving same error.